# rpath of a shared object file

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, rpath

The `rpath` of an executable specifies one or more directories wherein to look for shared objects at runtime.

My question is - do shared object files *themselves* also have statically-compiled `rpath`s?

I recently received a runtime error when linking with a shared object:

```
./example: /opt/swt/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by ./mylib.so)
```

This error indicates to me that the actually library itself - `mylib.so`, has an statically compiled `rpath`.

My understanding was that `rpath` only applied to executables, not shared objects.  So does `rpath` *also* apply to shared objects?

Answer (score 11):

> do shared object files themselves also have statically-compiled `rpaths`

They may (or may not) depending on whether they were linked with `-Wl,-rpath=...` option.

> This error indicates to me that the actually library itself - `mylib.so`, has an statically compiled `rpath`.

The error message does *not* say that at all. Where did you get that idea?

If you want to know whether `mylib.so` has `DT_RPATH` or not, do this:

```
readelf -d mylib.so | grep 'R.*PATH'  # could also have RUNPATH
```

> My understanding was that `rpath` only applied to executables, not shared objects. So does `rpath` also apply to shared objects?

Your understanding is incorrect, and `RPATH` (and `RUNPATH`) works for shared objects just as well.